# What's the NuGet target for plain Mono?

Tags: mono, nuget, target

NuGet [documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/create/targetframeworks) is quite clear: there is no target for plain Mono projects. We have Monoandroid, Monotouch, Monomac, and a few flavours of Xamarin for various platforms.

On one hand, if Mono is binary compatible to .NET, it shouldn't need different DLLs. And indeed "Mono is binary compatible with Windows. Which means that you can run binaries produced by .NET compilers from Microsoft and other vendors." according to the [Mono FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/technical/).

On the other hand, "Mono does not have every .NET API implemented and when executing a binary from Windows that consumes an unimplemented API you might get an obscure message about tokens not being found."

So I think we need a specific Mono target. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

Your point is absolutely correct, but as everything in opesource - you need to implement it yourself (or hire me :) )

Comment: As far as I can see it, this isn't a Mono issue but rather a NuGet issue. Of course Xamarin Studio (aka Mono Develop) must also support the NuGet target.

Comment: By the way, the point is all about porting Windows Forms control libraries: the code behaves differently on .NET and Mono. So it can't be the same DLL.

Comment: This was published today at Xamarin blogs. It looks like I asked the question a few days ahead of time.
https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-library-support-for-xamarin/

Comment: Mono is  listed on the .NET Standard Library matrix as Mono /Xamarin Platforms but i don't understand the symbols on that line. So it doesn't really solve the problem.

This problem concerns not only UI agnostic libraries but also Windows Forms control libraries as Mono's Windows Forms implementation isn't exactly the same as .NET implementation.

I don't understand why Mono/Xamarin/NuGet (well, they are all Microsoft, aren't they?) don't address the issue.